# Selenium find_elements_by_class_name not returning full list

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape some data from a website with Selenium and Python 3 but facing some issues.

The code of the site I am trying to fetch the info from:

```html
<uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="select-container" style="height: 1777px;">
    <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-list-wrap">
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="0" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">36</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥3789</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="1" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">37.5</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥3899</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="2" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">38.5</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥3839</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="3" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">40</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥3479</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="4" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">41</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥3629</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="5" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">42.5</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥3869</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="6" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">44</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥4099</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="7" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">45</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥4409</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="8" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">46</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥4209</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="9" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">47.5</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥5079</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="10" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">48</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥--</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
        <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" data-section="0" data-row="11" data-item="[object Object]" class="select-size-info  cover-info">
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size">48.5</uni-view>
            <uni-view data-v-13033eed="" class="size-price">¥--</uni-view>
        </uni-view>
    </uni-view>
</uni-view>
```

I want to fetch the class "size-price" and print every element that has been found. My code looks like this:

```
find_price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('size-price')
for item in find_price:
print(item.text)
```

However, only 4 of 12 elements get returned.

This is what I see in the console:

```
¥4209
¥5079
¥--
¥--
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the web page need several time to perfect load web page, so may you need wait to solve your issue.

Utilize this method `.presence_of_all_elements_located`:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
find_price = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'size-price')))

for item in find_price:
    print(item.text)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I have driver.implicitly_wait(10) implemented twice in there since I first have to click a button on the page to show the prices I want to fetch. What I noticed is that I get 12 results as expected, but 8 of them are simply empty which is quite strange.

Comment: @tymz96 You have tried `item.get_attribute('innerHTML')` ?

Comment: Yes, same result.